# How to fix error Illegal character at line 4 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a code that will merge a Google  document with a Spreadsheet.When the code executes instead of it working it shows an error "Incorrect Characters" at line 4.

```
function mailMerge() {
  var db, doc;
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(‘NONE’);
  if (files.hasNext())
    db = files.next();
  else
    return;
  files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('DB7’);
                                  if (files.hasNext())
  doc = files.next();
  else
    return;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(db.getId());
  var template = DocumentApp.openById(doc.getId());
  var message = DocumentApp.create('message') .getBody();
  var par = template.getBody().getParagraphs();
  var val = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
  var i, j, str;
  for (i=1; i<val.length; i++) {
    str = val[i][0] + ‘ ‘;
    if (val[i][1] == 'v’)
        str += ‘mister’;
        else
        str += ‘miss’
        var p;
        for (j=0; j<par.length; j++) {
      p = par[j].copy();
      vestule.appendParagraph(p); }
    vestule.replaceText('{name}', str);
    vestule.appendPageBreak();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using wrong quotes. `‘` instead of `'` or `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @str points out, you're using invalid characters for single quotes: `‘` and `’`.

Replace them for standard single (`'`) or double quotes (`"`) and you'll be good to go.

You'll need to fix this issue in a few lines:

- line 3: `‘NONE’`
- line 8: `'DB7’`
- line 20: `‘ ‘`
- line 21: `'v’`
- line 22: `‘mister’`
- line 24: `‘miss’`